# Nested sum in replacement rule of unknown size

Tags: replacement, summation

I have a function which takes a list as its argument, and I want to transform it by multiplying by a matrix for each element of a list. To be specific, I want the following transformation: $$\hat{f}_i = \sum_p^n A_{ip}f_p, \quad \hat{f}_{ij} =\sum_i^n \sum_j^n A_{ip}A_{jq} f_{pq}, \quad \hat{f}_{ijk} =\sum_i^n \sum_j^n \sum_k^n A_{ip} A_{jq} A_{kr} f_{pqr}$$
and so on.

I can write some replacement rules to do this explicitly for each size of the list,

```
n = 4;
reps = {f[{i_}] :> Sum[A[i, p] f[{p}], {p, 1, n}],
 f[{i_, j_}] :> Sum[A[i, p] A[j, q] f[{p, q}], {p, 1, n}, {q, 1, n}],
 f[{i_, j_, k_}] :> Sum[A[i, p] A[j, q] A[k, r] f[{p, q, r}], {p,1,n}, {q,1,n}, {r,1,n}]}
```

For the first order, I get

```
f[{1}] /. reps
(* A[1, 1] f[{1}] + A[1, 2] f[{2}] + A[1, 3] f[{3}] + A[1, 4] f[{4}] *)
```

with increasingly large expressions for the longer lists. The large expressions are fine, and speed is not a concern. I want to manipulate them symbolically, without assuming values for the matrix `A` at this point.

I need a solution that takes any size list (up to say length 12), and figure there  must be a better way than explicitly listing them out.

Comment: Note that speed is not my primary goal here, and I don't have an explicit matrix of numbers, I want to do this symbolically.

Answer (score 3):

Using [`TensorContract`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TensorContract) with [`TensorProduct`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TensorProduct) won't be as fast as [`Compile`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Compile) or [`Dot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Dot) solutions, but might be more understandable:

```
transform[A_][tensor_] := With[{rank = TensorRank[tensor]},
    Activate @ TensorContract[
        Inactive[TensorProduct] @@ Append[ConstantArray[A, rank], tensor],
        Table[{2 i, 2 rank+i}, {i, rank}]
    ]
]
```

*(see this [answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/111544/45431) for an explanation of the use of [`Inactive`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Inactive) here)*

Here are examples for ranks 1, 2, and 3:

```
b1 = transform[A][f1]; //RepeatedTiming
b2 = transform[A][f2]; //RepeatedTiming
b3 = transform[A][f3]; //RepeatedTiming
```

> {0.000080, Null}
>
> {0.00011, Null}
>
> {0.00030, Null}

and a check with @HenrikSchumacher's answer:

```
a1 == b1
a2 == b2
Block[{Internal`$EqualTolerance = 4}, a3 == b3]
```

> True
>
> True
>
> True

**Addendum**

Based on your comment, perhaps the following variation of my answer is more like what you're looking for:

```
transform[A_, t_, indices_] := TensorContract[
    TensorProduct @@ Append[A[[#]]& /@ indices, t],
    Table[{i, i+Length[indices]}, {i, Length[indices]}]
]
```

Examples:

```
transform[Array[A, {4,4}], Array[f, 4], {1}]
transform[Array[A, {4,4}], Array[f, {4,4}], {1,3}]
```

> A[1, 1] f[1] + A[1, 2] f[2] + A[1, 3] f[3] + A[1, 4] f[4]
>
> A[1, 1] A[3, 1] f[1, 1] + A[1, 1] A[3, 2] f[1, 2] + A[1, 1] A[3, 3] f[1, 3] + 
>    A[1, 1] A[3, 4] f[1, 4] + A[1, 2] A[3, 1] f[2, 1] + A[1, 2] A[3, 2] f[2, 2] +
>     A[1, 2] A[3, 3] f[2, 3] + A[1, 2] A[3, 4] f[2, 4] + 
>    A[1, 3] A[3, 1] f[3, 1] + A[1, 3] A[3, 2] f[3, 2] + A[1, 3] A[3, 3] f[3, 3] +
>     A[1, 3] A[3, 4] f[3, 4] + A[1, 4] A[3, 1] f[4, 1] + 
>    A[1, 4] A[3, 2] f[4, 2] + A[1, 4] A[3, 3] f[4, 3] + A[1, 4] A[3, 4] f[4, 4]

Comment: I do not have an explicit tensor, I just have a list of indices. I want to manipulate it symbolically before giving any numbers.

Comment: The addendum version does what I need, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Better store the `f` and `A` as vectors and matrices and use `Dot`. That's easier and much, much faster.

```
n = 10;
A = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {n, n}];
f1 = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {n}];
f2 = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {n, n}];
f3 = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {n, n, n}];

a1 = A.f1; // AbsoluteTiming
b1 = Table[
 Sum[A[[i, p]] f1[[p]], {p, 1, n}], 
 {i, 1, n}]; // AbsoluteTiming
Max[Abs[a1 - b1]]
```

> {8.*10^-6, Null}
>
> {0.000152, Null}
>
> 0.

```
a2 = A.f2.A\[Transpose]; // AbsoluteTiming
b2 = Table[
    Sum[A[[i, p]] A[[j, q]] f2[[p, q]], {p, 1, n}, {q, 1, n}],
    {i, 1, n}, {j, 1, n}]; // AbsoluteTiming
Max[Abs[a2 - b2]]
```

> {0.000014, Null}
>
> {0.019346, Null}
>
> 1.33227*10^-15

The third one is a bit more involved:

```
b3 = Table[
    Sum[A[[i, p]] A[[j, q]] A[[k, r]] f3[[p, q, r]], {p, 1, n}, {q, 1,
       n}, {r, 1, n}],
    {i, 1, n}, {j, 1, n}, {k, 1, n}]; // AbsoluteTiming
a3 = Compile[{{A, _Real, 2}, {B, _Real, 2}}, A.B,
     RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable},
     Parallelization -> True
     ][A, A.f3.A\[Transpose]]; // AbsoluteTiming
Max[Abs[a3 - b3]]
```

> {2.66485, Null}
>
> {0.000152, Null}
>
> 5.32907*10^-15

Comment: I want a replacement rule that will work for any size list. I can't see how to generalise what you have written to do that.